# Plotting line graph with factors in R

Tags: r, graph

I am working on this graph in R:

[image: graph]

However as you see I am getting these solid dashes instead of nice lines. Here is the code I used to make this graph:

```
par(mar = c(5,5,2,5))
    with(bedtimes, plot(trap, funestus, type="l", col="red3", 
                 ylab=expression(italic(p))),
                 ylim=c(0,3))  

    par(new = T)
    with(bedtimes, plot(trap, bed, pch=16, axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA, cex=1.2))
    axis(side = 4)
    mtext(side = 4, line = 3, 'Proportion in bed')
    polygon(bedtimes$bed,col=transp("gray", 0.3), border = NA)
```

And here is the dput of the data I am using:

```
(removed)
```

I realise that this is occurring because my x axis is a factor and not numeric. However, trying to change this (e.g. using  `as.POSIXct(paste0("2016-07-12",bedtimes$trap))` is causing me all sorts of problems, as I had to ake sure R plotted these factors in the correct order originally by using `bedtimes$trap <- factor(bedtimes$trap, levels = bedtimes$trap)`

How can I produce this same graph but with lines instead of these dashes?
I eventually want a graph that looks similar to this, to give you an idea (though not exactly the same):

[image: graph]

Thank you!

Comment: try using `as.numeric(trap)` = the level numbers instead of the labels (and also `type="l"` instead of `pch=16` if what you want is lines)

Comment: By level numbers do you mean the times on the x axis?

Comment: I mean `as.numeric(trap)` instead of `trap` and then you label your axis with `levels(trap)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comments, you can try to use the levels of your factor variable:

```
par(mar = c(5,5,2,5))
with(bedtimes, plot(as.numeric(trap), funestus, type="l", col="red3", 
                    ylab=expression(italic(p))),
                    ylim=c(0,3))  
par(new = T)
with(bedtimes, plot(as.numeric(trap), bed, type="l", axes=F, xlab="", ylab=NA, cex=1.2))
axis(4)
axis(side = 1, at=1:length(levels(bedtimes$trap)), levels(bedtimes$trap))
mtext(side = 4, line = 3, 'Proportion in bed')
polygon(bedtimes$bed,col="gray", border = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this removes the y axis on the left hand side and the line I had for funestus. I'm looking to create a plot like the one in the example picture with the two y axis and the separate plots

Comment: @SamuelHarper sorry, I just didn't take the first part of your code. The image is not exactly the one you'll have using your parameter of transparancy

Comment: That is great thank you! If I could ask you one more thing (and this is completely optional since you have already answered my question!) 

How do I rotate my axis labels so they are easier to read? As they are a bit too long to fit horizontally.

Comment: With parameter las ;-)